Entire phone wiped, no partitions, no GPT, only EDL
I have a ZTE nubia Red Magic 7 on Android 13. I accidentally had to erase all checked in QFIL when trying to bring it back from soft bricked. That's irrelevant now though as erase all did just that. 0 partitions. 0 GPT headers.
I have backups from before in QFIL. However, this is not working either as they are all snippets for QFIL to use. I have a full partition list from before d and a few readings from the partition manager as well, user and system I believe, maybe different, can't read it to tell.
0 help on XDA. 0 help from the manufacturer. 0 help from Qualcomm. 0 help online.
How can I bring this phone back from death?
